# I have a UK DClinPsy. Can I use a plain 'Dr.' title in Germany?

Tags: united-kingdom, germany, titles, accreditation

A resposible german executive body (Kultusministerkonferenz) [decided](http://www.kmk.org/fileadmin/Dateien/pdf/PresseUndAktuelles/Beschluesse_Veroeffentlichungen/Hochschule_Wissenschaft/BS_080515_VereinbarungGrundsaetzeAuslHSGrade.pdf) that certain doctorates from the EU grant the right to use the title 'Dr.':

> Inhaber von in einem wissenschaftlichen Promotionsverfahren erworbenen Doktorgraden, die
>   in [meiner Uni] erworben wurden, können anstelle der
>   im Herkunftsland zugelassenen oder nachweislich allgemein üblichen Abkürzung [...] wahlweise die Abkürzung „Dr.“ [...] führen. Dies gilt nicht für Doktorgrade, die ohne
>   Promotionsstudien und -verfahren vergeben werden (so genannte Berufsdoktorate) und für
>   Doktorgrade, die nach den rechtlichen Regelungen des Herkunftslandes nicht der dritten
>   Ebene der Bologna-Klassifikation der Studienabschlüsse zugeordnet sind.

excluding non third cycle qualifications (Bolonga EHEA term) and doctorates that do not require some not further defined sort of studies ("doctoral" studies) with professional doctorates given as example. However, a UK doctor of clinical psychology (DClinPsy) is usually considered [equivalent](http://www.qaa.ac.uk/publications/information-and-guidance/publication?PubID=2975#.V_nHa2UXZSA) to a PhD.

So, am I allowed to use Dr. MyName in Germany?

And will I be after Brexit?

Comment: My reading of the intention of the Google-translated version of the text is that holders of recognised doctorates can be called "Dr", but not holders of degree-mill "doctorates" awarded "in recognition of professional expertise" without requiring extra study.

Comment: No, the exemption is not about degree-mill "docorates" but Berufsdoktorate (which I think translates to "first professional graduate degree") like an USA M.D. .

Comment: IANAGerman, but have you tried searching for your title on the [Anabin](http://anabin.kmk.org/no_cache/filter/hochschulabschluesse.html) database?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni good advice. But yes, I had tried (and did again), however, it only contains information on the bachelor in Clinical psychology.

Answer (score 4):

There is a department in every state in Germany at the Kultusminister / Senator for Science & Education that deals with exactly this issue. You submit your degree papers and they will tell you in a written letter if your degree is able to be used as "Dr." in Germany. But we are trying so hard to lose this business in Germany about being "Herr Doktor" and "Frau Doktor", why would you want this? Indeed, the KMK paper is just about the EU partners, so if there is a Brexit, this may change. No one knows yet what the results of Brexit will be.

Comment: "whay would you want this?" I'm from austria and we got that too. Why do you want a title here? Because it makes life easier if you use it in the right situations (for example at the bank). Ofc, (ab)using the system won't make it go away but why would I not take advantage of the hard work I've put into that degree.

Comment: @DSVA because you perpetuate this annoying misuse of the degree by continuing to use it outside. "Dr." should be used at university and research institutions only. At the Kita parent's meeting or getting a dentist's appointment you should be an ordinary citizen. You did get the degree because you like to do research, didn't you, and not to put it on a brass plate on your apartment door?

Comment: Ofc I didn't get my degree because I wanted to have that degree and yes, at a parents meeting or such things it's stupid to state it. At the bank if they don't want to give you that credit but right the moment they see your "Dr" they accept it...well in that case you will always state your degree there. Or would you really not use it in that case because you think it's unethical?
And funny you mentioned the dentist, at mine I get less waiting time and get treated nicer since the medical insurance company put that title on my e-card without asking...

Comment: @DSVA, I do think that we should strive to achieve a world in which all people are treated with respect and there are no "special deals" for certain groups of people. But I'm afraid we are getting off topic with this.

Comment: @DeboraWeber-Wulff It's a nice brass plate, though.

Comment: Nothing will change with Brexit, definitely not if you have already used your right and been a *Doktor* in Germany. Vertrauensschutz is a very strong legal principle.