# When to use academic titles in presentations in Europe?

Tags: presentation, engineering, physics, titles, medicine

I have M.Sc. (tech.) in physics. I am doing second degree in MD. I normally just present my work without academic titles in MD studies. 
I am thinking the benefits of using academic titles in different fields. 
Some of my friends use MD in medical stuff, while M.Sc. (tech.) in technical stuff.

However, many times, I have to deal with epidemiology and statistics where I use tools in Physics. 
In these cases, I am thinking if I should use the academic title because my work is so different than anyone else in the group. 
Same goes for the reports which I write.

In Finnish culture, we do not want to emphasize what you have achieved, which is the reason I am not using the academic title. 
However, I am not sure about it.

Other titles which I can use EUR ING soon. 
I think it is extraneous in such presentations. 
Not sure which are the rules when to use this one, for example. 
I think it is enough to leave the latter in CV.

Comment: Do you mean presentations in the academic context (i.e. conferences), in the industry/company context, for governmental agencies or for the general public? The use of the title/degree differs amongst the contexts - i.e. in presentations in front of a academic audience I would not put my degree on the slides.

Comment: Exactly! Those are use cases about which I am interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you live in a culture where flaunting one's title(s) comes across as a bit crass; at the same time, you wonder if mentioning your title on the first page of a powerpoint presentation might increase your credibility when you are presenting to certain audiences.  (Did I get that right?)

You may be able to get the idea across in a more subtle way, that people would not interpret as bragging, on the first or second slide, as an acknowledgment.  For example, you could acknowledge the mentorship of Prof. XX in the YY Master's program at ZZ University.

That's just an example.  Does it give you some ideas?

Comment: Great idea! The challenge is how generally you can use it. Etc you do presentation about basic statistics and epidemiology of this disease in causing these manifestasions in this speciality. It is already so multifactorial where I need to work hard with R to answer the topic. - - I find it frustrating with some audiences sometimes. - - I would like to thank very often Schrödinger institut and R core team for their great work, because without their great work, I would not do what I do. However, not sure if enough subtle way. What do you think?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 - I think you need to run it past some fellow Finns, or at least some fellow Scandinavians.  I lived in Denmark for two years and I noticed that it's quite difficult for outsiders to give meaningful feedback about regional cultural norms.  (But to me your draft sounds fine.)

Comment: I do not think so it is about Finns, I need to ask. I work in international environment which consists of swedish, germans, autrians, ... students. There is so big gap between scandinavian and German cultures. - - The problem is that you never know when the presentation what you listen is really evidenced-based. Mostly, they are not so it is safest to assume that none of such presentations is completely evidenced-based and check the facts always yourself. - - I am not sure how I should deal with the problem because there are no guidelines for the cultures working together.

Comment: Why not make an informal survey of your peers? // Take a look at http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/79832/32436.